# hiding rows from JTable

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I want to hide those rows from JTable containg a particular string....please help me for this..

Answer (score 3):

You can use [javax.swing.RowFilter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) for that. Detailed usage instructions are in the linked API docs.

Comment: You'll need to specify a TableRowSorter (use setRowSorter from JTable) and set your RowFilter of the TableRowSorter per setRowFilter

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 1.6 there is a ready to use RowFilter version that takes regexp as a parameter, so that would be the easiest approach in your case.

Have a look at [that section of Swing tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) and [RowFilter Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#regexFilter(java.lang.String,%20int...)).